# Getting overlapping circles (or any shapes) along a closed curve in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have been trying to figure out how I can have overlapping circles along the path of a closed curve. I have seen that if I use the Bezier curve commands, then I can almost kind of get what I'm looking for but it's very difficult to construct curves with that (at least for me). Using the code I have below, it doesn't seem to work at all; I only get the picture below the code. Is there way to have overlapping circles covering this closed curve (kind of like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Analytic_continuation_3.png)) by modifying the code I have below (instead of using the `controls` curve commands)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[line width=0.05cm] (6,6) to [closed, curve through = {(4.2,6) (0,4) (-4,4) (-6,0) (-4.2,-5.2)
(-1.5,-5.2) (3,-4)}] (5,-2) foreach \t in {0,0.1,0.2,...,1} {pic [pos=\t] {code={\draw[line width=0.02cm,blue]
circle [radius=1cm];}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `decorations.markings` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.markings,%<-- added
    hobby,                
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
        name=markings,
        mark=between positions 0. and 1. step .1 with {\draw[line width=0.02cm,blue] circle [radius=1cm]; }
    }
    ](6,6) to [closed, curve through = {%
    (4.2,6) (0,4) (-4,4) (-6,0) (-4.2,-5.2)(-1.5,-5.2) (3,-4)}] (5,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew there would be an uncomplicated answer. Thanks so much!